# Instructions appear to be wrong when performing a tag search

Tags: bug, search

I received the [following message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLlgW.png), when searching for the tag `[isomorphism]`

```
The isomorphism tag has no wiki summary, can you help us create it?

learn more… | top users | synonyms

You are on the Featured tab.
There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.
Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enter `[isomorphism]` in the search box
2. Arrive at this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isomorphism
3. Note the above listed message

I am confused as to what the "Featured tab" is - there is no tab called "Featured" on the page, and I did not specifically select any tab (only searched).

[image]

After clicking the `newest` tab, [I am correctly shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXdTZ.png) a list of results for the `[isomorphism]` search.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty certain this is not a bug. The site "remembers" what tab you've been on when you view questions. For example, if I'm on the "featured" tab, then click on your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isomorphism), it shows the "featured" tab. Anyone who was on the "newest" tab will see the "newest" tab. The easiest way to see this effect is to have two windows open.

Comment: Ahh, in that case, it should at the very least *show* a "Featured" tab, yes? See my screenshot from the question for what I saw: http://i.imgur.com/JK5lIAC.png